# How can I apply Data validation and conditional formatting on the drop down list?

Tags: validation, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I want to add data validation for a list of dates (Jan 1st 2023 to December 31st 2023) to a column. When the user click on the drop down. I want them to see the Current day date highlighted. How can i do this?

I have added the necessary data validation rule to the column. Clicking on the date column, I want it to do something like what I have in the picture below.

That blue color is not an highlight. It's my cursor

[image: 1]

Comment: That's not possible.

Comment: It's not possible in a dropdown, but maybe this is useful: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/insert-calendar-excel-datepicker-template/#:~:text=Insert%20a%20calendar%20control&text=To%20insert%20it%20in%20your,select%20it%2C%20and%20click%20OK.

Comment: I like this Date picker http://samradapps.com/datepicker